# How to delete a folder with other files and folders inside with PHP

Tags: php, delete-file, rm, rmdir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A recursive remove directory function for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407338/a-recursive-remove-directory-function-for-php)

With PHP

I want to know the easiest way  for delete a folder with files and folders inside.

Answer (score 2):

This trick from the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php#100092) is pretty cool:

```
function rrmdir($path)
{
  return is_file($path)?
    @unlink($path):
    array_map('rrmdir',glob($path.'/*'))==@rmdir($path)
  ;
}
```

It exploits `array_map`, which calls the given function on an array of results. It's also cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

`system("rm -fr $foldername");`

It only works on unix though, but it is easy.

Comment: I do not recommend doing this, but if you must, please make sure you (a) use `escapeshellcmd` on `$foldername` before calling this, and (b) be careful of the path you're executing from. I'd make sure `$foldername` is an absolute path, just to be safe.

Comment: Thank you and have you in a way that is independent of the shell to Unix?

Answer (score 0):

This recursive function has been posted as a [comment on the rmdir() function reference page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#98622):

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $objects = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
                if (filetype($dir . "/" . $object) == "dir")
                    rrmdir($dir . "/" . $object);
                else
                    unlink($dir . "/" . $object);
            }
        }
        reset($objects);
        rmdir($dir);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was posted here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

```
if(!file_exists($directory) || !is_dir($directory)) { 
    return false; 
} elseif(!is_readable($directory)) { 
    return false; 
} else { 
    $directoryHandle = opendir($directory); 

    while ($contents = readdir($directoryHandle)) { 
        if($contents != '.' && $contents != '..') { 
            $path = $directory . "/" . $contents; 

            if(is_dir($path)) { 
                deleteAll($path); 
            } else { 
                unlink($path); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    closedir($directoryHandle); 

    if($empty == false) { 
        if(!rmdir($directory)) { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 

    return true; 
}
```

}