# PHP Calling function within itself bricks

Tags: php, function, recursion, foreach, directory

I am using PHP in oder to recursively remove a directory.
When calling this function:

```
function deleteDir($dirPath) {

        $files = glob($dirPath . '*', GLOB_MARK);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (is_dir($file)) {
                deleteDir($file);
            } else {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
        rmdir($dirPath);
}
```

Using this line:

```
deleteDir("dir_to_be_deleted_recursively/");
```

It goes wrong here:

```
deleteDir($file);
```

(When the function detects a directory within the directory it is trying to delete, it calls the function again, but for that dir.)

This is the directory i am testing it with:

```
dir_to_be_deleted_recursively/
   dir1/
      subdir1/
         file1.txt
      subdir2/
         file2.txt
      subdir3/
         file3.txt
```

Note: i am not getting an error, just a blank page.

Comment: Make sure you have enabled error reporting. Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the very top of your script and try again.

Comment: Thanks, now i am getting: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` and a lot of `Warning: directory not empty` Warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found the solution!

Simply using this piece of code works perfectly:

```
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirPath, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $path) {
    $path->isFile() ? unlink($path->getPathname()) : rmdir($path->getPathname());
}
rmdir($dirPath);
```

Source: [A recursive remove directory function for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407338/a-recursive-remove-directory-function-for-php)