# Delete Directory and All Files Within

Tags: php, file, directory, copy, unlink

I used the following line to create a directory on my server:

```
mkdir("/var/www/cache/$directory", 0700);
```

Then I copied some files into it using this:

```
copy($remote, $local);
```

Now I'm trying to delete the directory and all of its file with this, but it will not work:

```
$local = "/var/www/cache/$directory";
$removed = unlink($local);
```

Is there anyway to do this with a one-liner and not a for loop or the such?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `RecursiveIteratorIterator` class in php.

A simple example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-files-sub-dir) would be

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);

foreach ($files as $fileinfo) {
$todo = ($fileinfo->isDir() ? 'rmdir' : 'unlink');
$todo($fileinfo->getRealPath());
}

rmdir($dir);
```

There are many methods described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407338/a-recursive-remove-directory-function-for-php) too..