# Creating Zip folder on button click and remove folder from original folder in PHP

Tags: php, zip

I want to remove folder from destination folder.
My Destination folder is:=pdf-files/

```
In that pdf-files/folder-1/
Now in folder1/subfolder-1
       folder1/subfolder-2
       folder1/.pdffile
```

Now when I download in zip folder-1 it's download but with download I also remove/delete whole folder-1 from pdf-files folder.

This is my zip file code:-

```
<?php
$sMainFolder = $_GET['main_folder'];
$sFolder = $_GET['folder_name'];
$the_folder = $sMainFolder.$sFolder;
$zip_file_name = $sFolder.'.zip';
$download_file= true;
//$delete_file_after_download= true; 
class FlxZipArchive extends ZipArchive {
    /** Add a Dir with Files and Subdirs to the archive;;;;; @param string $location Real Location;;;;  @param string $name Name in Archive;;; @author Nicolas Heimann;;;; @access private  **/

    public function addDir($location, $name) {
        $this->addEmptyDir($name);

        $this->addDirDo($location, $name);
     } // EO addDir;

    /**  Add Files & Dirs to archive;;;; @param string $location Real Location;  @param string $name Name in Archive;;;;;; @author Nicolas Heimann
     * @access private   **/
    private function addDirDo($location, $name) {
        $name .= '/';
        $location .= '/';

        // Read all Files in Dir
        $dir = opendir ($location);
        while ($file = readdir($dir))
        {
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
            // Rekursiv, If dir: FlxZipArchive::addDir(), else ::File();
            $do = (filetype( $location . $file) == 'dir') ? 'addDir' : 'addFile';
            $this->$do($location . $file, $name . $file);
        }
    } // EO addDirDo();
}

$za = new FlxZipArchive;
$res = $za->open($zip_file_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if($res === TRUE) 
{
    $za->addDir($the_folder, basename($the_folder));
    $za->close();

}
else  { echo 'Could not create a zip archive';}
if ($download_file)
{
    ob_get_clean();
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($zip_file_name) . ";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file_name));
}

?>
```

Above script download the folder but not remove folder form pdf-files folder

Comment: Just remove the `$the_folder` manually using techniques from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407338/a-recursive-remove-directory-function-for-php#15111679)

Comment: I use destroy_dir function and call it after if ($download_file)
{    ob_get_clean();  } it  removes all subfolder from folder-1 but not remove folder-1.

Comment: Add `rmdir('path/to/folder-1')` after that. The directory should be empty by that time and removable.

Comment: Ok let me try this.

Comment: above solution not working @ruslan bes